# How to open process substituted file from php?

Tags: bash, shell, php, process-substitution

Here's what I tried to do myself:

```
$ type 1.sh
#!/bin/bash -eu
php -r 'var_dump(file_get_contents($_SERVER["argv"][1]));' -- <(echo 1)
$ ./1.sh
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/dev/fd/63): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Warning: file_get_contents(/dev/fd/63): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
bool(false)
```

I tested it on `Debian 6` (`php-5.4.14`, `bash-4.1.5`) and `Arch Linux` (`php-5.4.12`, `bash-4.2.42`).

**UPD**

```
$ strace -f -e trace=file php -r 'var_dump(file_get_contents($_SERVER["argv"][1]));' -- <(echo 1)
...
open("/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mongo.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
lstat("/dev/fd/63", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0500, st_size=64, ...}) = 0
readlink("/dev/fd/63", "pipe:[405116]"..., 4096) = 13
lstat("/dev/fd/pipe:[405116]", 0x7fff5ea44850) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/dev/fd", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=13, ...}) = 0
readlink("/dev/fd", "/proc/self/fd"..., 4096) = 13
lstat("/proc/self/fd", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0500, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/self", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=64, ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self", "31536"..., 4096) = 5
lstat("/proc/31536", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/proc/31536/fd/pipe:[405116]", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/dev/fd/63): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Warning: file_get_contents(/dev/fd/63): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
bool(false)

$ strace -f -e trace=file php <(echo 12)
...
open("/usr/lib/php5/20100525/mongo.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/dev/fd/63", O_RDONLY)            = 3
lstat("/dev/fd/63", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0500, st_size=64, ...}) = 0
readlink("/dev/fd/63", "pipe:[413359]", 4096) = 13
lstat("/dev/fd/pipe:[413359]", 0x7fffa69c3c00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/dev/fd/63", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0500, st_size=64, ...}) = 0
readlink("/dev/fd/63", "pipe:[413359]", 4096) = 13
lstat("/dev/fd/pipe:[413359]", 0x7fffa69c19b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("/dev/fd", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=13, ...}) = 0
readlink("/dev/fd", "/proc/self/fd"..., 4096) = 13
lstat("/proc/self/fd", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0500, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc/self", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=64, ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self", "32214"..., 4096) = 5
lstat("/proc/32214", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lstat("/proc", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
2
```

Comment: Do this: `strace -f -e trace=file php -r ...`

Comment: I added output of `strace` to the question, please take a look.

Comment: Process Substitution -- <(cmd) and >(cmd), See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Expansions 
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: @Rany Albeg Wein What exactly do you mean with your links? Are there any information explaining the issue?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you want php to read input from a file descriptor, but you force it to read like regular file.

First, try this:

```
$ echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

then you can process `ls` output by reading `/dev/fd/63`. The process substitution will return the `file descriptor`, which is use by other command to reading its output.

In your case, you use `$_SERVER["argv"][1]`, meaning that php will interpreter like this:

```
file_get_contents(/dev/fd/63)
```

From php manual, you can see protorype of `file_get_contents` function:

```
string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path =
false [, resource $context [, int $offset = -1 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )
```

Ops, php will consider `/dev/fd/63` as normal file here, but it's really a `file descriptor`.

To access file descriptor, you must use `php://fd`, `php://fd/63` will access content of file descriptor 63:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(file_get_contents("php://".substr($_SERVER["argv"][1],-5)));' -- <(echo test.txt)
string(9) "test.txt
"
```

You can see, now php can process content in `/dev/fd/63`. But our purpose is reading content of file, which is provide via process substitution (In my example, it's `test.txt`). I don't know much about php, so I add another `file_get_contents`:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(file_get_contents(file_get_contents("php://".substr($_SERVER["argv"][1],-5))));' -- <(echo -n test.txt)
string(13) "Hello world!
"
```

I use `echo -n` to remove newline from echo ouput, otherwise, php will see the ouput "test.txt\n".

**Note**

For more information about accessing file descriptor in php, you can see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Comment: This clears things up a bit. But the important thing here is why can't `php` do as everybody does and just open the file? Like: `cat <(echo test)`. Also, you're wrong about your wording. I don't want `php` to read input from a file descriptor, process substitution doesn't return file descriptors and so on. `/dev/fd/*` files are files of `procfs` (virtual filesystem), which correspond to file descriptors of the process. You can't open file descriptor. They are means by which we specify to the kernel, what open file we're talking about.

Comment: What do you mean "everybody"?`cat <(echo test)` meaning `cat /dev/fd/63` and will print `test` because `cat` have done its job, like you do `cat /path/to/regular_file`. You can see more here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution - to know why process substitution return a file descriptor.

Comment: Let's see: `ruby -e 'p File.read ARGV[0]' <(echo test)`, `perl -e 'open F, @ARGV[0]; print <F>' <(echo test)`, `cat <(echo test)`. They all don't try to dereference the link and just output what they're asked. As opposed to `php`. Because that's what `open` system call does. Do you have any counterexamples? Also, your `wikipedia` article has no word `descriptor` in it. Process substitution returns a symbolic link to non-existent file, which corresponds to a file descriptor.

Comment: @x-yuri: You should reading the article carefully, esspecially section Limitations. And you should know ruby `File.read`, perl diamond operator `<>` is very **different** with php `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I'd read that article before you mentioned it. And I understand that the pipes are not seekable, and therefore not all the programs will be able to work with process substitution. The question is why exactly php can't work with process substitution, what prevents it from doing that? `perl`, `ruby`, `bash` and whatnot deal with it just fine. Do you know any other languages with similar problems? Also, I do understand that `File.read` and `<>` are different from `file_get_contents`, but not in the context of the discussion. Considering the topic, they just read a file.

Comment: No, `file_get_contents` can only read regular file, see the manual page for more details.

Comment: Also, it works in `nodejs`: `node -e 'var fs = require("fs"); fs.readFile(process.argv[1], "utf8", function(err, data) { console.log(data); })' <(echo test)` and [`c`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124951/29867). And the manual says: `A URL can be used as a filename with this function`

Comment: `URL` is different with `path`. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php for more details.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. For one reason or another, `php` doesn't deal with paths like `/dev/fd/*`. Although it has full right to do so, the question is what prevents it from handling such files. As you may see, `Hauke Laging` shares my opinion. Anyway, let's see [what](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67085) the developers has to say :)

Comment: On a side note, it's better (safer) to use `basename` instead of `substr` in your code.

Comment: @x-yuri: Yeap, I only use for this example. Looking for responing from developer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
readlink("/dev/fd/63", "pipe:[405116]"..., 4096) = 13
lstat("/dev/fd/pipe:[405116]", 0x7fff5ea44850) = -1 ENOENT
```

Without any good reason (IMHO) `php` tries to get the real name of the link target. Unfortunately the link target is not part of the file system thus the try to access that name fails and causes this error. The symlink can only be opened as such. I consider this a bug in `php`. You could use a FIFO instead:

```
mkfifo /my/fifo; output_cmd >/my/fifo & php -r ... /my/fifo
```

Comment: But php, opening the file on its own, makes the same system calls and the file is opened successfully. See updated question.

Comment: @x-yuri There is neither a "file" nor "on its own". In both cases there is a `lstat("/dev/fd/pipe:[405116]", 0x7fff5ea44850) = -1 ENOENT` call. Unfortunately the second block ends one line too early. What does the `open()` call to the file look like? Maybe php can be tricked into opening the link path instead of the "physical" path. But that cannot be forced from the outside.

Comment: There is no more system calls for php <(echo 12) case. I only forgot to add output of the script itself.

Comment: @x-yuri The file is obviously **not** opened if there is no `open()` or `openat()`. The missing error message does not mean that the file was opened successfully.

Comment: I meant, there is only one call to `open()`, on the second line of the output (`open("/dev/fd/63"...`) . Not at the end. So, the file is opened. And the script is run, so the file is opened successfully. Just in case... do note who tries to open the file: `php -r '...file_get_contents(...' -- <(echo 12)` - the file is opened by the script. `php <(echo 12)` - the file is opened by php itself and contains the script.

Comment: @x-yuri: I think the file descriptor `63` is opened by bash, not php.

Comment: @Gnouc Indeed, you're [right](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124947/how-process-substitution-is-implemented-in-bash).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I just figured out the answer so I thought I'd share. Maybe it will help someone.

You can use the `php://` stream wrapper to open the file descriptor instead:

```
 $fd = $argv[1];
 $handle = fopen(str_replace('/dev/','php://',$fd));
```

So instead of opening the `/dev/fd/[nn]` file descriptor provided by the OS. You'll be opening `php://fd/[nn]` which will work. I'm not sure why opening the file descriptor fails on some systems but not others.

This was an [old bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53465) and was supposed to have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using...

```
php -r "var_dump(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));" < <(echo this is a win)
```

If you're trying to do other stuff with stdin this obviously won't work for you, and this is no different from

```
php -r "var_dump(stream_get_contents(STDIN));" < <(echo this is a win)
```

which leads me to wonder what it is you were actually trying to do, and why are you stuck on file_get_contents? :)

Reference - http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: I was trying to embed php script into bash script, see my [first question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74363/whats-wrong-with-embedding-php-scripts-inside-bash-ones).