# Difference between subshells and process substitution

Tags: process, process-substitution, subshell

In bash, I want to assign my current working directory to a variable. Using a subshell, I can do this.

```
var=$(pwd)

echo $var
/home/user.name
```

If I use process substitution like so:

```
var=<(pwd)

echo $var
/dev/fd/63
```

I have understood that process substitution is primarily used when a program does not accept STDIN. It is unclear to me what a process substitution exactly does and why it assigns `/dev/fd/63` to `var`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A command substitution (`$(...)`) will be replaced by *the output* of the command, while a process substitution (`<(...)`) will be replaced by *a filename* from which the output of the command may be read. The command, in both instances, will be run in a subshell.

In your case, the output from `pwd` in `<(pwd)` may be found at `/dev/fd/63`.  This file ceases to exist as soon as the command that *uses* the process substitution has finished executing (when the assignment to `var` in your example is done).

The filename returned by a process substitution is the name of a file descriptor or named pipe, not a regular file:

> Process substitution is supported on systems that
> support named pipes (FIFOs) or the `/dev/fd` method of naming open files.

A common use of process substitution is to pre-sort files for the `join` command:

```
$ join <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
```

or for removing columns from a file (here, column 2 is removed from a tab-delimited file by using `cut` twice and `paste` to stitch the result together):

```
$ paste <( cut -f 1 file ) <( cut -f 3- file )
```

Process substitution is more or less a syntactical shortcut for avoiding using temporary files explicitly.

---

Both command substitutions and process substitutions are performed in subshells.  The following shows that the environment in these subshells do not affect the parent shell's environment:

```
$ unset t
$ echo "$( t=1234; echo "$t" )"
1234
$ echo "$t"
(empty line output)
```

Here, `echo` gets `1234` as a string argument from the command substitution.

```
$ unset t
$ cat <( t=4321; echo "$t" )
4321
$ echo "$t"
(empty line output)
```

Here, `cat` get the filename of a file (named pipe/file descriptor) as its argument.  The file contains the data `4321`.

Comment: Is there a way to "open" / look inside `/dev/fd/63` somehow to directly see "what's inside" ? I could not yet make good sense of [this Q&A on that matter, but it might have some valid points.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124947/how-process-substitution-is-implemented-in-bash)

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty To any process opening and reading what's on that path, it would be equivalent to reading from a pipe, i.e., you would be able to read the data (which would be the output of the command in the process substitution), but you can't seek backwards or forwards in the stream. It's a bit unclear what you mean by "open/look inside".

Comment: I'm just trying to get my head around, and my hands dirty with https://askubuntu.com/a/1456103/16023; of all the stuff I'm looking into, this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2444163/2153622 helps.