# The process substitution output is out of the order

Tags: bash, process-substitution

The

```
echo one; echo two > >(cat); echo three;
```

command gives unexpected output.

I read this: [How process substitution is implemented in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124956/109397) and many other articles about process substitution on the internet, but don't understand why it behaves this way.

**Expected output:**

```
one
two
three
```

**Real output:**

```
prompt$ echo one; echo two > >(cat); echo three;
one
three
prompt$ two
```

Also, this two commands should be equivalent from my point of view, but they don't:

```
##### first command - the pipe is used.
prompt$ seq 1 5 | cat
1
2
3
4
5
##### second command - the process substitution and redirection are used.
prompt$ seq 1 5 > >(cat)
prompt$ 1
2
3
4
5
```

Why I think, they should be the same? Because, both connects the `seq` output to the `cat` input through the anonymous pipe - [Wikipedia, Process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution#Mechanism).

**Question:** Why it behaves this way? Where is my error? The comprehensive answer is desired (with explanation of how the `bash` does it under the hood).

Comment: Even if it's not so clear at first sight, it's actually a  duplicate of [bash wait for process in process substitution even if command is invalid](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/388519)

Comment: Actually, it would be better if that other question was marked as a duplicate to this one as this one is more to the point. Which is why I copied my answer there.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, in `bash` like in `ksh` (where the feature comes from), the processes inside the process substitution are not waited for (before running the next command in the script).

for a `<(...)` one, that's usually fine as in:

```
cmd1 <(cmd2)
```

the shell will be waiting for `cmd1` and `cmd1` will be typically waiting for `cmd2` by virtue of it reading until end-of-file on the pipe that is substituted, and that end-of-file typically happens when `cmd2` dies. That's the same reason several shells (not `bash`) don't bother waiting for `cmd2` in `cmd2 | cmd1`.

For `cmd1 >(cmd2)`, however, that's generally not the case, as it's more `cmd2` that typically waits for `cmd1` there so will generally exit after.

That's fixed in `zsh` that waits for `cmd2` there (but not if you write it as `cmd1 > >(cmd2)` and `cmd1` is not builtin, use `{cmd1} > >(cmd2)` instead as [documented](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-process-substitution)).

`ksh` doesn't wait by default, but lets you wait for it with the `wait` builtin (it also makes the pid available in `$!`, though that doesn't help if you do `cmd1 >(cmd2) >(cmd3)`)

`rc` (with the `cmd1 >{cmd2}` syntax), same as `ksh` except you can get the pids of all the background processes with `$apids`.

`es` (also with `cmd1 >{cmd2}`) waits for `cmd2` like in `zsh`, and also waits for `cmd2` in `<{cmd2}` process redirections.

`bash` does make the pid of `cmd2` (or more exactly of the subshell as it does run `cmd2` in a child process of that subshell even though it's the last command  there) available in `$!`, but doesn't let you wait for it.

If you do have to use `bash`, you can work around the problem by using a command that will wait for both commands with:

```
{ { cmd1 >(cmd2); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat; } 4>&1
```

That makes both `cmd1` and `cmd2` have their fd 3 open to a pipe. `cat` will wait for end-of-file at the other end, so will typically only exit when both `cmd1` and `cmd2` are dead. And the shell will wait for that `cat` command. You could see that as a net to catch the termination of all background processes (you can use it for other things started in background like with `&`, coprocs or even commands that background themselves provided they don't close all their file descriptors like daemons typically do).

Note that thanks to that wasted subshell process mentioned above, it works even if `cmd2` closes its fd 3 (commands usually don't do that, but some like `sudo` or `ssh` do). Future versions of `bash` may eventually do the optimisation there like in other shells. Then you'd need something like:

```
{ { cmd1 >(sudo cmd2; exit); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat; } 4>&1
```

To make sure there's still an extra shell process with that fd 3 open waiting for that `sudo` command.

Note that `cat` won't read anything (since the processes don't write on their fd 3). It's just there for synchronisation. It will do just one `read()` system call that will return with nothing at the end.

You can actually avoid running `cat` by using a command substitution to do the pipe synchronisation:

```
{ unused=$( { cmd1 >(cmd2); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&-); } 4>&1
```

This time, it's the shell instead of `cat` that is reading from the pipe whose other end is open on fd 3 of `cmd1` and `cmd2`. We're using a variable assignment so the exit status of `cmd1` is available in `$?`.

Or you could do the process substitution by hand, and then you could even use your system's `sh` as that would become standard shell syntax:

```
{ cmd1 /dev/fd/3 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cmd2 4>&-; } 4>&1
```

though note as noted earlier that not all `sh` implementations would wait for `cmd1` after `cmd2` has finished (though that's better than the other way round). That time, `$?` contains the exit status of `cmd2`; though `bash` and `zsh` make `cmd1`'s exit status available in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` and `$pipestatus[1]` respectively (see also the `pipefail` option in a few shells so `$?` can report the failure of pipe components other than the last)

Note that `yash` has similar issues with its process *redirection* feature. `cmd1 >(cmd2)` would be written `cmd1 /dev/fd/3 3>(cmd2)` there. But `cmd2` is not waited for and you can't use `wait` to wait for it either and its pid is not made available in the `$!` variable either. You'd use the same work arounds as for `bash`.

Comment: Firstly, I tried `echo one; { { echo two > >(cat); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat; } 4>&1; echo three;`, then simplified it to the `echo one; echo two > >(cat) | cat; echo three;` and it outputs values in the right order, too. Does all this descriptor manipulations `3>&1 >&4 4>&-` are necessary? Also, I don't get this `>&4 4>&` - we are redirect `stdout` to the fourth fd, then closing fourth fd, then again use `4>&1` it. Why it needed and how it works? May be, I should create new question on this topic?

Comment: @MiniMax, but there, you're affecting the stdout of `cmd1` and `cmd2`, the point with the little dance with the file descriptor is to restore the original ones and using only the extra pipe for the _waiting_ instead of also channelling the output of the commands.

Comment: @MiniMax It took me a while to understand, I didn't get the pipes at such a low level before. The rightmost `4>&1` creates a file descriptor (fd) 4 for the outer braces command list, and makes it equal to outer braces' stdout. The inner braces has stdin/stdout/stderr automatically setup to connect to the outer braces. However, `3>&1` makes fd 3 connect to the outer braces' stdin. `>&4` makes the inner braces' stdout connect to the outer braces fd 4 (The one we created before). `4>&-` closes fd 4 from the inner braces (Since inner braces' stdout is already connected to out braces' fd 4).

Comment: @MiniMax The confusing part was the right-to-left part, `4>&1` gets executed first, before the other redirects, so you don't "again use `4>&1`". Overall, the inner braces is sending data to its stdout, which was overwritten with whatever fd 4 it was given. The fd 4 that the inner braces was given, is the outer braces' fd 4, which is equal to the outer braces' original stdout.

Comment: Bash makes it feel like `4>5` means "4 goes to 5", but really "fd 4 is overwritten with fd 5". And before execution, fd 0/1/2 are auto connected (Along with any fd of the outer shell), and you can overwrite them as you wish. That's at least my interpretation of the bash documentation. If you understood something else out of [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), lmk.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone, `4>&5` means redirect fd 4 to the same resource as on fd 5. It duplicates the fd 5 onto fd 4.

Comment: Yeah, with 5 not noticing at all. It seems similar to pointers, if 4 is a pointer you set 4 to 5, they both now point to the same thing. (Typo before, `4>&5` not `4>5`)

Comment: Is there a way to make cmd1 stay in the current shell (i.e. no subshell fork) ?
That's an advantage of process substitution AFAIK, but then indeed all output gets badly  desynchronized.

Answer (score 7):

You can pipe the second command into another `cat`, which will wait until its input pipe closes. Ex:

```
prompt$ echo one; echo two > >(cat) | cat; echo three;
one
two
three
prompt$
```

Short and simple.

==========

As simple as it seems, a lot is going on behind the scenes. You can ignore the rest of the answer if you aren't interested in how this works.

When you have `echo two > >(cat); echo three`, `>(cat)` is forked off by the interactive shell, and runs independently of `echo two`. Thus, `echo two` finishes, and then `echo three` gets executed, but before the `>(cat)` finishes. When `bash` gets data from `>(cat)` when it didn't expect it (a couple of milliseconds later), it gives you that prompt-like situation where you have to hit newline to get back to the terminal (Same as if another user `mesg`'ed you).

However, given `echo two > >(cat) | cat; echo three`, two subshells are spawned (as per the documentation of the `|` symbol).

One subshell named A is for `echo two > >(cat)`, and one subshell named B is for `cat`. A is automatically connected to B (A's stdout is B's stdin). Then, `echo two` and `>(cat)` begin executing. `>(cat)`'s stdout is set to A's stdout, which is equal to B's stdin. After `echo two` finishes, A exits, closing its stdout. However, `>(cat)` is still holding the reference to B's stdin. The second `cat`'s stdin is holding B's stdin, and that `cat` will not exit until it sees an EOF. An EOF is only given when no one has the file open in write mode anymore, so `>(cat)`'s stdout is blocking the second `cat`. B remains waiting on that second `cat`. Since `echo two` exited, `>(cat)` eventually gets an EOF, so `>(cat)` flushes its buffer and exits. No one is holding B's/second `cat`'s stdin anymore, so the second `cat` reads an EOF (B isn't reading its stdin at all, it doesn't care). This EOF causes the second `cat` to flush its buffer, close its stdout, and exit, and then B exits because `cat` exited and B was waiting on `cat`.

A caveat of this is that bash also spawns a subshell for `>(cat)`! Because of this, you'll see that

`echo two > >(sleep 5) | cat; echo three`

will still wait 5 seconds before executing `echo three`, even though `sleep 5` isn't holding B's stdin. This is because a hidden subshell C spawned for `>(sleep 5)` is waiting on `sleep`, and C is holding B's stdin. You can see how

`echo two > >(exec sleep 5) | cat; echo three`

Will not wait however, since `sleep` isn't holding B's stdin, and there's no ghost subshell C that's holding B's stdin (exec will force sleep to replace C, as opposed to forking and making C wait on `sleep`). Regardless of this caveat,

`echo two > >(exec cat) | cat; echo three`

will still properly execute the functions in order, as described previously.

Comment: As noted in the conversion with @MiniMax in the comments to my answer, that has however the downside of affecting the stdout of the command and means the output needs to be read and written an extra time.

Comment: The explanation is not accurate. `A` is not waiting for the `cat` spawned in `>(cat)`. As I mention in my answer, the reason why `echo two > >(sleep 5 &>/dev/null) | cat; echo three` outputs `three` after 5 seconds is because current versions of `bash` waste an extra shell process in `>(sleep 5)` that waits for `sleep` and that process still has stdout going to the `pipe` which prevents the second `cat` from terminating. If you replace it with `echo two > >(exec sleep 5 &>/dev/null) | cat; echo three` to eliminate that extra process, you'll find that it returns straight away.

Comment: It makes a nested subshell? I've been trying to look into the bash implementation to figure it out, I'm pretty sure the `echo two > >(sleep 5 &>/dev/null)` at the minimum gets its own subshell. Is it a non-documented implementation detail that causes `sleep 5` to get its own subshell too? If it's documented then it would be a legitimate way to get it done with fewer characters (Unless there's a tight loop i dont think anyone will notice performance problems with a subshell, or a cat)`. If it's not documented then rip, nice hack though, won't work on future versions though.

Comment: `$(...)`, `<(...)` do indeed involve a subshell, but ksh93 or zsh would run the last command in that subshell in the same process, not `bash` which is why there's still another process holding the pipe open while `sleep` is running an not holding the pipe open. Future versions of `bash` may implement a similar optimisation.

Comment: A would still be waiting for `>(sleep 5)` though, wouldn't it? It wouldn't be able to close because if it closed then B would close immediately, since it's no longer connected to `>(sleep 5)` using A as a proxy. Even if `>()` doesn't get its own subshell, wouldnt `A` have to wait for it?

Comment: If by `A` you mean the subshell that handles the left part of the pipeline, then no, that subshell dies after running the `echo` builtin. But an extra subshell remains, the one that interprets the inside of the command substitution. And that's the one that holds the pipe open (and prevents `cat` from exiting). Try `bash -c 'echo "$BASHPID" >(sleep 5) | cat' & sleep 1; ps -H`

Comment: Ah, so because they're passing file descriptors, `>()` isn't actually connected to A at all, it's connected directly to B without any proxy. Okay, so I see the subshell matters for sleep, but in the case of `>(cat)` as shown in the question, shouldn't it hold the pipe open, even if `>()` doesn't get its own subshell, since `>(cat)` is holding the fd of B's stdin as its own stdout. If it's true then no subshell would be even better, because we dont care if sleep 5 is skipped, we want it to skip. Only `>(cat)` matters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80655/discussion-between-nicholas-pipitone-and-stephane-chazelas).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I updated my answer and I think the current explanation of the shorter version is correct, but you seem to know implementation details of shells so you can verify. I think this solution should be used as opposed to the file descriptor dance though, since even under `exec`, it works as expected.