# Can `grep` output matched contents and full counts together? If not, how to?

Tags: grep

## Question 1

I can use

```
grep -o '^[[:alpha:]_]\+[[:blank:]]*([[:blank:]]*)' /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
```

to get output like below:

```
systemctl_redirect ()
checkpid()
__kill_pids_term_kill_checkpids()
__kill_pids_term_kill()
__pids_var_run()
__pids_pidof()
daemon()
killproc()
pidfileofproc()
pidofproc()
status()
echo_success()
echo_failure()
echo_passed()
echo_warning()
update_boot_stage()
success()
failure()
passed()
warning()
action()
strstr()
is_ignored_file()
is_true()
is_false()
apply_sysctl()
```

And I also want to know how many occurrences had been matched, so I use `-c` option, this time I only get `26`, can I combine matched contents and counts with `grep` ***built-in*** options? If not, how to?

## Question 2

I found a solution on Github to answer Question 1:

```
grep -o '^[[:alpha:]_]\+[[:blank:]]*([[:blank:]]*)' /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions \
| tee >(echo -e "\n`wc -l` matched.")
```

But the output is often weird, which is output after a new ***shell prompt***! Why?

[image: output after a new shell prompt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do:

```
grep -o ... | awk '{print};END{if (NR) print "\n" NR " matched."}'
```

Or do the whole thing in `awk` (which would also avoid the `-o` and `\+` GNUisms):

```
awk 'match($0, /^[[:alpha:]_]+[[:blank:]]*\([[:blank:]]*\)/) {
       print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
       n++
     }
     END{if (n) print "\n" n " matched.")'
```

or `perl`:

```
perl -lne 'for (/^\w+\h*\(\h*\)/g) {print; $n++}
           END {print "\n$n matched." if $n}'
```

(note that in that case the `\w` is limited to ASCII letters, add a `-Mopen=locale` to include any letter in any alphabetical script according to locale like in the `grep` or `awk` (some `awk`) approaches)

About your question 2, that's because `bash` (contrary to `zsh`) doesn't wait for commands started in process substitution causing this kind of problem. See [The process substitution output is out of the order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403783) for more details.

Comment: You answered the Question 1, thanks. But I also want to know the answer of Question 2, are there any idea? Is @agc said `there's no guarantee which process finishes first` true?

Comment: @liyang, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tee` use a tool like [`pee`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
grep -o '^[[:alpha:]_]\+[[:blank:]]*([[:blank:]]*)' /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions | 
pee cat 'sleep 1; echo -e "\n`wc -l` matched."'
```

---

If `pee` isn't available, it can be done with a separate `bash` shell, and silence its prompts with `unset` and `shopt`:

```
bash -c \
    "unset PS0 PS1 PS2 PS3
     shopt -u promptvars
     grep -o '^[[:alpha:]_]\+[[:blank:]]*([[:blank:]]*)' \
          /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions |
     tee >( sleep 1s; printf '\n%s matched.' `wc -l`; )
     sleep 2s"
```

---

General answers:

1. Can't be done with a single instance of `grep`.

   To get a full count when there's more than one match per line with
   `grep -o`, use `wc -l`:

   ```
   printf "foo bar baz\nbuz biz\n" | grep -o 'b[^ ]*' | wc -l
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   4
   ```

   If a prefixed count is needed, use `nl`, (or `cat -n`):

   ```
   printf "foo bar baz\nbuz biz\n" | grep -o 'b[^ ]*' | nl
   ```

   Output:

   ```
        1  bar
        2  baz
        3  buz
        4  biz
   ```
2. With parallel processes, *i.e.*

   ```
   tee >(echo -e "\n`wc -l` matched.")
   ```

   there's no guarantee which process finishes first. 
   Sometimes a little delay can be added to insure the order.

   Print parallel "*foo*" first, then "*oof*" after a 1 second delay:

   ```
   echo foo | tee >(sleep 1s; rev)
   ```

   Print parallel "*oof*" first, then "*foo*" after a 1 second delay:

   ```
   echo foo | tee >(rev) >(sleep 1s;cat) > /dev/null
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but ```tee >(sleep 1s; echo -e "\n`wc -l` matched.")``` can't solve my problem.

Comment: @liyang, Please provide more detail on what sort of solution is required.  Specifically, what should the output look like?

Comment: The output should like this: https://i.imgur.com/MdwPeBN.png. My problem is: the last line `26 matched.` was output at correct place this time, but will be placed after a new shell prompt next time, and I want to control it.