# Add timestamp to stderr redirect

Tags: linux, bash

I'm running a script on my machine that produces a lot of output as it runs. I redirect that output to `/dev/null` because I'm not interested in its contents, and I capture any errors in a file (since I only care if the script fails). However, the errors in the file do not include a timestamp.

Is there a way to append a timestamp to the stderr redirect?  This is the command I have, but can't figure out how to add the timestamp:

`myScript.sh 2>> logfile.txt 1>/dev/null`

I can't modify myScript.sh to print a date so that's not an option either.  I tried something like this:

`myScript.sh 2>> logfile.txt << date`

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`ts` from `moreutils` can be used to add timestamps to each line of some output:

```
myScript.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null | ts >> logfile.txt
```

You can specify the timestamp format in a `strftime()`-like format:

```
$ seq 4 | ts '%FT%.T%z:'
2023-06-06T14:11:15.244613+0100: 1
2023-06-06T14:11:15.244693+0100: 2
2023-06-06T14:11:15.244729+0100: 3
2023-06-06T14:11:15.244759+0100: 4
```

For instance for a ISO8601 timestamp format with microsecond precision.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend `ts`. And an output [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) would fit here:

```bash
myScript.sh 2> >(ts >> logfile.txt) 1>/dev/null
# ............^ yes that space is required.
```

Comment: That should be avoided in bash, as bash doesn't wait for processes started in process substitutions. See [The process substitution output is out of the order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403783)

Answer (score 0):

You can call print the date before the script execution, like this:

`echo "$(date >> logfile.txt; ./myscript.sh 2>> logfile.txt 1>/dev/null)`