# Why does dd dislike taking input from process substitution?

Tags: dd, process-substitution

Is there something about process substitution (which I think is [implemented with unnamed pipes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124956/11985)) that is incompatible with `dd`?

For example, this fails:

```
$ dd if=<(unzip -p raspbian.zip) of=/dev/sdb status=progress        
dd: unrecognized operand ‘/dev/fd/4’
Try 'dd --help' for more information.
```

But this works fine:

```
$ unzip -p raspbian.zip | dd of=/dev/sdb status=progress       
108458496 bytes (108 MB) copied, 19.446285 s, 5.6 MB/s
```

Is the use of `if` somehow implicitly telling `dd` that it [should be able to seek](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164109/11985)?

Comment: Hmm... standard input over a pipe isn't seekable either.

Comment: @Kusalananda right -- that's why I'm wondering if `if` is implying that the input *should be* seekable.

Comment: Your first example lists an error from `dd`, which doesn't show up under bash. What shell do you use?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `cat` replacing `unzip` (I don't have Zip archives) in `bash` nor `zsh` on OpenBSD using either of GNU `dd` or OpenBSD `dd`.  Did you originally have a space before the process substitution? That would make GNU `dd` complain as you show.

Comment: Simple test: `dd if=<(echo foo) of=/dev/null` works for me, but `dd if= <(echo foo) of=/dev/null` gives an error `dd: unrecognized operand ‘/dev/fd/63’`  similar to that described in the question.  I don't know which shell will pick fd 4 for its first process substitution.  Try also `echo if=<(:)` to see if your shell is introducing a space where it shouldn't.

Comment: @TobySpeight you got it!  I'm using ksh (specifically "Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01").  Trying `$ echo if=<(:)` produces `if= /dev/fd/4` (with a rogue leading space).  ARGH!

Comment: I'll make that an answer, then.

Comment: In any case, you don't want to use `dd` on a pipe or to write to block devices. Just use `unzip -p raspbian.zip > /dev/sdb` or `unzip -p raspbian.zip | pv > /dev/sdb` if you want a progress status.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks.  I left off some of the extras in my pipeline -- e.g., I use the `bs` parameter of `dd` to (perhaps vainly) optimize the drive I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be caused by your shell adding leading whitespace (or otherwise performing argument splitting) when expanding the process substitution.  We can demonstrate this:

```
$ echo if=<(:)
if= /dev/fd/4
```

Assuming that this behaviour is reproducible on the most recent version you can get, I think there's nothing you can do here other than submit a bug report, including the justifying case of `dd` to demonstrate that the bug causes real problems.

You might consider switching shells, but I can understand if that's unpalatable to you!